# Using production settings with database migration plugin

Tags: grails, database-migration

I'm trying to follow the tutorial [here](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/08/17/countdown-to-grails-2-0-database-migrations/).

I have declared the dependency for the database migration plugin in my BuildConfig.groovy file with `runtime ":database-migration:1.0"` and then compiled.  I have also comment out the `dbCreate` line of my production settings in my DataSource.groovy file.  My production database is empty with no tables in it.

I then try to run the two commands to generate my initial change log:

```
grails dbm-create-changelog
grails prod dbm-generate-gorm-changelog --add changelog-1.0.groovy
```

The problem is the first command creates tables in my development database, not my production database.  Then the second command fails to create the `changelog-1.0.groovy` file it is supposed to create (I assume) because the production database never had any tables created.  I get several errors that say Hibernate failed to index the database and I a bunch of errors like this:

```
| Error 2012-07-10 08:40:28,704 [Compass Gps Index [pool-11-thread-2]] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Table 'mygrailsapp_prod.some_class' doesn't exist
```

Even when I comment out my development settings in my DataSource.groovy file Grails is still looking for my development database.  I should point out though if I drop the `prod` off the second command a the `changelog-1.0.groovy` file generates fine, though I am unclear if will somehow be messed up because it was generated off the development database (which had no tables in it until I ran the first command) instead of the production database.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The problem is the first command creates tables in my development database, not my production database.
```

That's probably because it is running against the development environment and you still have its dbCreate set to "update"

```
Then the second command fails to create the changelog-1.0.groovy file it is supposed to create (I assume) because the production database never had any tables created.
```

That's not entirely accurate.  From the link you posted it says after that step: "Note that your database will remain empty!"  The database tables will only get created when you execute a dbm-update command.  That's when the changelog actually executes.

I think the blog you linked to isn't entirely accurate on the prod switch for the second command.  Nothing about your Domains is environment specific.  So just leave that off and you should be able to keep going.  I'm not sure why that error is being thrown.  It really doesn't make sense.

Comment: I had actually tried that. When I do prepend the first command with `prod` I get the same error that I was getting with the second command .

Comment: So when you run 'grails prod dbm-create-changelog' you get the Table 'mygrailsapp_prod.some_class doesn't exist' error?

Comment: Correct.  It is the exact same error that I was getting running `grails prod dbm-generate-gorm-changelog --add changelog-1.0.groovy`

Comment: Technically, all dbm-create-changelog does is create an empty changelog file.  So I suppose including prod in front of it doesn't matter.  I'm going to edit my answer...

Comment: I actually didn't expect any tables to be generated after running either of the commands, but the first command does indeed generate tables.

Comment: Like I said, it's because you probably have dbCreate set to "update" or "create" in your DataSource development block.  Change that to "none" and it won't create the tables.

Comment: If I remove the `dbCreate` line from my development environment settings and run `dbm-generate-changelog` I get the same warning that I have been getting.

Comment: Are you running it with 'prod' or without?  You don't need to use 'prod' for these commands.

Comment: I have been running without `prod` since I'm now trying to generate off development settings, but I'm getting the same errors.